# get object.properties and place it random in dom element.Vanila Js

Tags: javascript, object, dom, random, properties

I'm creating quiz game.
I have separate .js file with array of objects for questions,like this:

```
var questions = [
  {
    ask: "question",
    choice1: "answer",
    choice2: "answer",
    choice3: "answer",
    correct: "correct answer"
  },
];
```

then i get random object from array:

```
let random = questions[Math.floor(Math.random() * questions.length)];
```

then i can send these object.properties to dom like this:

```
question.innerHTML = random.ask
answer1.innerHTML = random.choice1;
answer2.innerHTML = random.choice2;
answer3.innerHTML = random.choice3;
answer4.innerHTML = random.correct;
```

And everything works fine but i need to randomize these answers.In ways like this every time the correct answer is on same place but i need answers and correct answer to take random place in dom.

I'm stuck in this problem,trying every solution i can find on google but no success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the same logic to randomize choices. One of the ways this can be done is as below:

```
var questions = [
  {
    ask: "question",
    choice1: "answer 1",
    choice2: "answer 2",
    choice3: "answer 3",
    correct: "correct answer"
  },
];

let random = questions[Math.floor(Math.random() * questions.length)];
console.log(random);
// Make an array of choices key
let choices = [];
Object.keys(random).forEach((item, index) => {
  if(key !== "ask") {
    choices.push(random[item]);
  }
});

console.log(choices);

function getRandomAnswer() {
    // Get a random number
    let randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * choices.length);
  // Store random answer in a variable
  let answer = choices[randomNum];
  // Remove used up answer from choices array
  choices.splice(randomNum, 1);
  return answer;
}

console.log("Random Answer: ", getRandomAnswer());
console.log("Random Answer: ", getRandomAnswer());
console.log("Random Answer: ", getRandomAnswer());
console.log("Random Answer: ", getRandomAnswer());
```

I have made a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharshuklaa/or5vdk7m/2/) of this as well. You can optimize this as per your needs.
Hope it helps!

Comment: Yes...Thank you so much,i manage to include in my code and it works great.

Comment: Glad I was able to help :) Can you please upvote this answer as well (up arrow button). And welcome to this huge Stackoverflow community.

Comment: That is the first thing I do when I find the problem is solved and its say that vote is recorded but not visible since have less than 15 reputations :)Thank you for the welcome :)